# Linux for 128 MB of memory

Tags: linux, memory

I need a Linux distribution which has got drivers for [pendrives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) and could play the music.
What version could you recommend for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT dated but valid list**.
Any one of these [10 of lightweight Linux distributions](http://lightlinux.blogspot.com/2008/06/top-10-of-lightweight-linux_24.html) should do

My suggestion is that you try a couple with [Live CD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_cd) before you choose to install one on the computer.

List from website in case of linkrot:

- Damn Small Linux
- Puppy Linux
- Feather Linux
- DeliLinux
- Vector Linux
- Zenwalk
- Antix
- TinyME

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you look at Slax : http://www.slax.org

It is small, fast and comes in an image for USB is you wish to try it via a USB memory stick.

Another really good optin is try out Puppy Linux. It too runs on small amounts of memory is fast and has a USB memory stick option.

Have Fun

Answer (score 1):

Xubuntu !

Xubuntu releases:
9.10, codename Karmic Koala (newest stable release).
8.04.1, codename Hardy Heron, includes Long Term Support.

Minimum system requirements
You need 192 MB RAM to run the Live CD or 128 MB RAM to install. 
The Alternate Install CD only requires you to have 64 MB RAM at install time.

Download:
http://www.xubuntu.com/get

Comment: anything *buntu is pretty useless on systems with only 128 MB RAM, even with Xfce.

Comment: Well, basically you have to remove the gui, and then you can use mplayer on the command line at lightening-speed. :)) apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras. Maybe the debian netinstall iso would be more appropriate, just there it's more of a pain to get the multimdedia working.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your familiarity with Linux, in particular if you are comfortable doing nearly everything from the command line, any distro can be pared down to be usable on that much ram, or much less (provided you can get the installer to run).

Some simple ways to reduce RAM/CPU usage: use ash instead of bash, use rxvt instead of xterm / gnome-terminal, use screen instead of having multiple terminals open, use rox-filer if you absolutely must have a graphic file system browser, use a lightweight window manager like evilwm or icewm instead of gnome or kde, learn how to do file management from the shell, use nvi instead of vim, use qemacs isntead of emacs, use links with the -g flag for web sites that are not ajax, use google chrome for ajax websites, use aptitude or apt-get instead of synaptic for package management (for debian-derived distros).

For more extreme paring down of RAM/CPU usage (and a matching loss of features) you can use things like busybox, the tools listed on [the diet libc page](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/) and the [linuxassembly](http://asm.sourceforge.net/resources.html#projects) web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at **[MacPup](http://www.macpup.org/)**, a beautifully remastered Puppy Linux and ideal for systems with little memory.

The current version comes with Firefox, personally, i like the previous release with Opera better.

Comment: puppy is a root-only system, which is really backward, and a huge security risk

Comment: @Justin Smith - good enough to play music on an old clunker with 128 MB and it supports pen drives (which is what the OP is asking for). i doubt 'security' is a major concern for this setup.